# Creating an option menu based on a text file?

Tags: javascript, html, file-io, filereader, optionmenu

I am trying to automatically create an option menu (using HTML and JavaScript) based on the contents of a text file.  What I would like is for each option in the menu to be a line in the text document.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function get_parameters() {
    alert("get_parameters() called"); // these alerts are just to tell me if that section of the code runs
    var freader = new FileReader();

    var text = "start";
    freader.onload = function(e) {
        text = freader.result;
        alert('file has been read');
    }

    freader.onerror = function(e) {
        alert('freader encountered an error')
    }

    freader.readAsText('./test.txt', "ISO-8859-1");

    var div = document.getElementById('bottom_pane_options');
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + text;
}
```

With this code, all I'm trying to accomplish is reading the file and printing to the `div` "bottom_pane_options" but I can't find any reason why it doesn't work.  If my way isn't the most efficient, could you please give me code that would work?

Thanks.

**--EDIT--**

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Culminating</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script
        src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCJnj2nWoM86eU8Bq2G4lSNz3udIkZT4YY&sensor=false">
    </script>

    <script>
        // Calling the Google Maps API
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div id="googleMap"></div>
        <div id="right_pane_results">hi</div>
        <div id="bottom_pane_options">
            <button onclick="get_parameters()">Try It</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: freader.readAsText wants a File object, not a string filename. change function get_parameters() to function get_parameters(file) and launch via <input type=file onchange=get_parameters(this.files[0]) />, and './test.txt' to e.

Comment: @dandavis Does that require the user to choose which file to read? If it is, that is not what I'm looking for. `test.txt` is a file in the same directory as the HTML and JavaScript file and contains data that might change depending on another program I run before.

Comment: in that case, use ajax. google up a simple ajax demo and customize it to your needs.

Comment: @dandavis Does AJAX require a server? I am running everything locally using my computer and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Because the file was not read yet when you are runing `div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + text;`.

That's why there are callbacks.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader :

> The FileReader object lets web applications **asynchronously** read the
>   contents of files [...]

Use this instead :

```
freader.onload = function(e) {
    text = freader.result;

    var div = document.getElementById('bottom_pane_options');
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + text;
    alert('file has been read');
}

freader.onerror = function(e) {
    alert('freader encountered an error')
}

freader.readAsText('./test.txt', "ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm a bit new to JavaScript, though.  How would I change the code so that `div.innerHTML = div.HTML + text;` runs when the file has been completely read and in an array?

Comment: @user3015565 Answer completed in the edit, as in the answer below

Comment: I tried what you suggested however it didn't seem to work.  If you have some time to help I could use it. (<-- I mean that in the least sarcastic way possible... I know it could be misconstrued as such)  If you do have some time, please see my last comment on `zero298`'s post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `<div>` text in the callback instead of right after you start loading:

```
freader.onload = function(e) {
   text = freader.result;

   /*************
    ** TO HERE **
    ************/

   alert('file has been read');
}

/* MOVE THIS */
var div = document.getElementById('bottom_pane_options');
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + text;
/*************/
```

Comment: @cubitouch I tried that and I get the first error, "get_parameters() called" but after that nothing happens.  `text.txt` only has 2 lines so it's not like `freader` is still reading the file.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3015565 Are you getting any errors in `console`? Post the pertinent HTML as well, because if your tags `id`'s are wrong, it won't get the element to replace its text.

Comment: This is the error I'm getting in the console.  This pops up as soon as I reload the page, not when I click or interact with anything: `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.`  I have also added the `HTML`.  See my edit.

Comment: @user3015565 This is not an error, only a warning. This do not block in any way the Javascript execution.

Comment: @cubitouch Okay.  Is there anything you can see in the HTML that might be the cause of my problem?

Comment: @user3015565 Are you sure about your file paths?  I usually use relative paths that look like: `imgs/whatevs.png` or `../res/imgs/pic.jpg` but I don't usually use `./thing.gif` I know that that is technically a correct path, but is that what might be causing the error?  I copy and pasted your code and loaded a different file and it worked fine.  Also, I removed `"ISO-8859-1"`

Comment: This function is not receiving a string but a blog/file object (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.readAsText)

Comment: @zero298 `./` was what my teacher told me to use which is supposed to look from the files' current directory onwards (if that makes sense).  I tried changing that line to `freader.readAsText('./test.txt')`, `freader.readAsText('G:\test.txt')`, and `freader.readAsText('G:\\test.txt')` but don't seem to be getting any results.

Comment: @cubitouch So if that is the case, I will try making a `File` object and using that object as a parameter for `freader.readAsText`.